# Making a Login with Firestore with Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I´m working in an android app for my school and i made a signup and login screen for students with firebase authentication and i made another login activity for teachers. I created a firestore collection and the documents inside of it contain an id and a password. I wanted to validate those things to log in but i did not found a way to validate data inside the collection, i tried searching in the official documentation but i only found how to make queries and show the data in the Logcat. Does anybody know how can i make the validation or knows a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store passwords in the database, that is not secure and also its a bad practice. Instead, firebase authentication does that job for you, the teachers and the students need to create their user first, in your sign up page.
After, when they want to log in, you need to ask for a password and the email that they used previously, when they hit the button "Log In" you get the data like this:

```
val password = myEditTextPassword.text.toString().trim(); 
val email = myEditTextEmail.text.toString().trim();

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                val user = auth.currentUser
                updateUI(user)
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                updateUI(null)
                // ...
            }

            // ...
        }
```

I think that you want to create the teacher users on your own, but you should not do it.
I recommend you take a look at the firebase auth documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?hl=en

Another approach is to create the teacher user manually in the console. In the tab of "Authentication" just press "add user", and it will ask you for an email and a password, create the users and in your teachers login page just use the code above. That is equivalent to "sign up" a user.

Sorry for my bad english